# Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, stompjs

I have a spring-boot websocket connection which sits behind spring-security-kerberos to achieve SSO.  This works as expected but if I restart the server I see clients fail to re-connect with the error `Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value`.

I am using [@stomp/stompjs](https://stomp-js.github.io/stomp-websocket/codo/extra/docs-src/Introduction.md.html) 4.0.8 and setting `stompClient.reconnect_delay = 5000`

Is there any way to solve this?  I am concerned that running this behind a load balancer would cause this error to occur all the time.

This is based on [the messaging-stomp-websocket example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) + [spring-security websocket-authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/web-app-security.html#websocket-authentication)

Comment: second link broken?

Comment: fixed the link.

Comment: don't have an answer for you but I'm having a similar problem which _seems_ to disappear when I remove the reconnect attempts entirely.

Comment: Well the problem goes away in the sense that stompjs doesn't attempt to re-connect so doesn't use a stale header...  Are you suggesting doing the re-connect manually?

Comment: just suggesting it's a place to start the investigation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that spring-security-web `RequestCacheAwareFilter` extracts a cached request which results in the actual **Sec-WebSocket-Key** header value being replaced with an invalid one.

The sequence of events is that each time the client attempts a re-connect the client makes two websocket requests, the first is rejected with a **WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate** header and the second which contains a **Authorization** header has a different **Sec-WebSocket-Key** value.

I was able to resolve this by disabling caching completely, e.g. within a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
}
```